# Remove "WWW" and ".html" and redirect to https only

Tags: .htaccess

My `.htaccess` file has the following code that removes the "WWW" from the URL. It also redirects to the HTTPS version of the site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

To this I want to add code that will remove the `.html` extension. I tried the following code,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

which did the job with the `.html` URLs but the folder URLs like `abc.com/def/` stopped working with a 404 error.

I want the following to happen,

- abc.com/def.html -> abc.com/def
- abc.com/def-> abc.com/def (Opens def.html)
- abc.com/def/ -> abc.com/def/ (Opens index.html in the def folder)

All of this combined with the removal of the leading "WWW" with HTTPS.

Comment: Have you tried adding .. `Options Indexes` above html rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if

```
Options Indexes
```

is written before last RewriteCond.

2) Modify last RewriteRule to exclude requests for directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```